# Get variable passed to switch statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

This isn't the exact use scenario but I was wondering if it was possible to get the value passed to the switch statement without having to retype what is in the `switch()` part.

Example :

```
switch(someObject.withSomevalue*(Math.random()*11)) {
    case 1 : alert("one");
    // more cases here
    default: alert(theNumberThatWasPassed);
}
```

If we run the `Math.random()` again we'll get another random number that very well could meet one of the cases, so calling what aws called in the switch(x) statement isn't an option. I've been just storing it in a variable - `x = someObject.withSomevalue*(Math.random()*11)` - and then passing it to the switch that way `switch(x)`, but I was wondering if it's possible to get the value passed to the switch within the switch statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same as asking if you can find the values for `if(Math.random()){...}`. The answer is no, because they are language constructs, and not functions.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I'll accept this as soon as the timeframe delay passes.

Answer (score 5):

As everyone else pointed out you have to save it in a variable. But you can do the following in the expression though I do not know how cross browser compatible this is:

```
  switch(x = <your expression>){
    //
    default:alert(x);
  }
```

and at least you save one line of code.

Comment: Well "x" has to be declared with a `var` statement unless it's ok for it to be global.

Comment: It's perfectly valid and the return value of the expression inside the switch will be `<your expression>`. ECMA-262 v5 11.13.1 step 6.

Answer (score 2):

Just capture it into a variable before the switch and use that variable.

```
var myValue = someObject.withSomevalue*(Math.random()*11);
switch(myValue) {
    case 1 : alert("one");
    // more cases here
    default: alert(myValue);
}
```

Comment: I'm already doing that, I was looking to see if there was another way.

Comment: Nope, the switch statement doesn't afford any API for recalling the value being compared. You need to just capture the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I would say your best bet would be to do what you currently are doing, and capture it into the variable before the switch statement. Is there any reason you would not want to do this besides saving a line of code?

Comment: Curiosity more than anything. If it's possible I'd like to know that it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting... OP, I'm trying to look at your thought process.  Maybe just write out the code how you think it should look like (ignoring that it wouldn't work in the first place).

update:

At least in C/C++, you can just form another block to have the var only be accessible within the switch:

```
...
{
    var mySwitchVar = blah;
    switch(mySwitchVar) {
        case blah blah blah:
        default blah blah:
    }
}
...
```

Comment: I didn't know if there was something like a "this.value" or whatever that would be private to only the switch statement.